# Is it fine to have a threshold greater than 1 in roc_curve metrics?

Tags: roc, auc

Predicting the probability of class assignment for each chosen sample from the `Train_features`:

```
probs = classifier.predict_proba(Train_features)`
```

Choosing the class for which the AUC has to be determined.

```
preds = probs[:,1]
```

Calculating false positive rate, true positive rate and the possible thresholds that can clearly separate TP and TN.

```
fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(Train_labels, preds)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
print(max(threshold))
```

Output : 1.97834

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The previous answer did not really address your question of why the threshold is > 1, and in fact is misleading when it says the threshold does not have any interpretation.

The range of threshold should technically be [0,1] because it is the **probability** threshold. But scikit learn adds +1 to the last number in the threshold array to cover the full range [0, 1]. So if in your example the max(threshold) = 1.97834, the very next number in the threshold array should be 0.97834.

See this [sklearn github issue thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3097) for an explanation. It's a little funny because somebody thought this is a bug, but it's just how the creators of sklearn decided to define threshold.

Finally, because it is a probability threshold, it does have a very useful interpretation. The optimal cutoff is the threshold at which sensitivity + specificity are maximum. In sklearn learn this can be computed like so

```
fpr_p, tpr_p, thresh = roc_curve(true_labels, pred)
# maximize sensitivity + specificity, i.e. tpr + (1-fpr) or just tpr-fpr
th_optimal = thresh[np.argmax(tpr_p - fpr_p)]
```

Comment: wonderful answer! It indeed looks like a bug. The max threshold should be 1, not max + 1

Answer (score 0):

The threshold value does not have any kind of interpretation, what really matters is the shape of the ROC curve. Your classifier performs well if there are thresholds (no matter their values) such that the generated ROC curve lies above the linear function (better than random guessing); your classifier has a perfect result (this happens rarely in practice) if for any threshold the ROC curve is only one point at (0,1); your classifier has the worst result if for any threshold the ROC curve is only one point at (1,0). A good indicator of the performance of your classifier is the integral of the ROC curve, this indicator is known as AUC and is limited between 0 and 1, 0 for the worst performance and 1 for perfect performance.